# How do I set up NET-SNMP with OpenVMS?

Tags: net-snmp, openvms

I'm having trouble getting started off with installing net-snmp. 
So far I've installed the binary for net-snmp version 5.6.1.1 on my Windows XP machine and I'm trying to install net-snmp on OpenVMS machine to make is as my client and the Windows machine as my host.

How do I go about on installing this? (I'm a total novice at this so I need all the help I can get...the net-snmp wiki didn't seem to answer my question, unless I'm looking at it wrong. :/)

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why install net-snmp on OpenVMS? SNMP is included in the TCPIP stack. 
Run @TCPIP$CONFIG (as SYSTEM) and enable SNMP in the server configuration.

Are you using OpenVMS Hobbyist license(s)? In that case you should be able to enable and start SNMP on OpenVMS. Lookup the TCPIP documentation on the HP site for directions on configuration.